# Git: (how) can I push a certain period of histroy to remote server?

Tags: git

```
                             #--#--#(hash_B)--#--#---\         Branch B
                            /                 \
---#---#---#---#(hash_A)---#---#---#---#---------------*       Branch A
```

I want to push commmits from hash_A to hash_B. How can I do it without exposing any other commits? And keep the local scenario the same as before?

Comment: are you looking for [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)? so on branch B you can cherry-pick commits from branch A

Comment: Create an orphan branch and cherry pick hash_A through hash_B from Branch B into orphan and push the orphan branch.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) (I named it `b1` below) on the `hash_B` commit and [push it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to the remote server:

```
git branch b1 hash_B
git push origin b1
```

It is not possible to push only the commits from `hash_A` to `hash_B`. The entire history of `hash_A` must also be present on the remote repository (it will be sent by `git push` if it is not already there).

---

If the remote repository is empty, I think it is possible to achieve the result you want (I didn't test it).

Create another local repository as a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt) of the local repository, setting the `hash_A` commit as the maximum depth it clones and `hash_B` as its current branch.

Assuming your local repo is named `local_repo1`, `cd` to its parent directory and run:

```
git clone --shallow-exclude=hash_A~1 --branch=hash_B local_repo1 local_repo2
```

Then add the remote repository as a remote of `local_repo2` and push

```
cd local_repo2
git remote set-url origin remote_repo_url
git push origin hash_B
```

*(The command above doesn't add a new remote but changes the URL of the `origin` remote. The effect is the same.)*

Comment: But the additional history before hash_A may contain passwords and etc.

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible solution. I didn't test it but it should work. I hope you can confirm it works :-)